# OR logic in Live Agent - doFind

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, pre-chat, pre-chat-api

I would like to know if it is possible to use OR logic in Live Agent prechat doFind event. I'm aware that you can enter multiple criteria there, and they will be linked with AND logic together. I can't find anything on online sources regarding using OR in doFind.

I tried below, but it did not work. Simply, I use two seperate doFind for each field that is subject to OR. I aim for constructing a query as "FirstName AND Last Name AND (PersonEmail OR Phone)". Form with matching firstname, lastname and email was successful but that with matching firstname, lastname and phone did not work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Account" value="PersonEmail,true;FirstName,true;LastName,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Account" value="PersonEmail,true;" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Account" value="Phone,true;FirstName,true;LastName,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Account" value="Phone,true;" />
```

Any clarification & help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks